# Priority in a broadcast receiver to receive calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My intention is to make a **Broadcast receiver** that performs actions when receiving a call. Is it possible that had more priority than the automatic call reception SO?.

I've tried assigning a priority of `2147483647` which I think is the best, but still jumps me to try the call before the end of my receiver.

```
<!-- Receiver de llamadas -->
<receiver android:name=".PhoneCall">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>   
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This link answer me:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

There are two major classes of broadcasts that can be received:

> - Normal broadcasts (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely asynchronous. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined
>     order, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that
>     receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.
> - Ordered broadcasts (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in
>     turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can
>     completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other
>     receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the
>     android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers
>     with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

Broadcast like PHONE_STATE are "Normal broadcast". As far as I understand it is not possible to prioritize my broadcast. Does anyone think of any way?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't think that 2147483647 is the best value to use, because Android won't understand it and will ignore this value.  What you have to do is try to set the priority to 999, since I guess 1000 is the maximum value.

Comment: refer to this google documentation for more info [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY)

Answer (score 0):

The value should be less the 1000!

Android developer docs:

**The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Comment: fyi, a few other stackoverflow answers on the topic recommend setting 1000 as the highest priority  integer.  And the Android Developer docs for IntentFilter suggest 1000 as a max for SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY int: 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY.  If true, then your statement above would become "...and less than or equal to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is creating two broadcast receivers.
The first receiver is used to receive the broadcast sent by the system with Action: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE.
The second receiver is called by the first receiver. (The first receiver will send a broadcast and I find that this broadcast will be received by the second receiver after all receivers receive  android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE.)

The detailed codes are show below:
The first receiver (CallReceiver.java):

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent newintent = new Intent(intent);
        newintent.setAction("");
        newintent.setClass(context, SecondReceiver.class);
        context.sendBroadcast(newintent);
    }
}
```

The second receiver (SecondReceiver.java):

```
public class SecondReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{  
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(
        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".SecondReceiver" />
```