# Keep Android call log cleared of certain numbers

Tags: android, calllog

I want to detect calls and delete certain numbers from call log from background. Below are the options I have considered. Please advise if any of these or another is a better/workable solution.

1. Register phone state broadcast receiver. Delete number from call log in onReceive. The problem is that the call log may not have been updated at this point and thus the delete will have no effect.
2. Register phone state broadcast receiver. In onReceive somehow add a delay and try to delete the call log after some time. The delay would give the system enough time to add a call log entry. This approach seems a bit hacky to me, not keen on this.
3. Register phone state broadcast receiver. In onReceive register content observer for call logs. My understanding is that after on receive the process may get killed at any time so content observers onChange will not get called if the process has been killed.
4. Register phone state broadcast receiver. In onReceive start my service (if not already running) which then has a content observer registered. Delete call log entries matching certain numbers in content observer onChange.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Option 4 is a perfect way to do it.
I would suggest that you stop your service after finishing the work and let the broadcast receiver restart it whenever required.

Edit : You may also note that BroadcastReceiver is only for performing some small or light work so delaying is not an option here. :)

Comment: Thanks ashu, I updated the question so option 3 is now option 4.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216920/how-to-stop-phone-calls-to-be-log-in-the-call-log-on-android?rq=1

Comment: also read the comment on accepted answer, its important : @Yash Khan

Comment: and The work in that post is performed without content observers so it can be done in onReceive() but I don't think that might be best way as in some devices, logs may appear a little delayed.!