# Android, How to prevent the screen call display

Tags: java, android

I'm developing caller id application and till now i'm able de detect incoming call and replace the default screen call following :

```
public class IncomingCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras == null)
        return;
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (state == null)
        return;

    // phone is ringing
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        Call.launch(context);

    }
```

However, the issue we are facing is as follows:
When phone gets incoming call our custom screen call start after 1sec the default incoming call screen gets priority and gets displayed.

My question is: is there a way to prevent default screen call display ?
or is there a trick to get priority for my custom incoming call screen ?
Thanks.

Comment: look at this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817178/priority-in-a-broadcast-receiver-to-receive-calls)