# How to run the broadcast receiver after other broadcast receivers ? android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

How to tell the android system to run my broadcast receiver after finishing running the other broadcast receivers ?

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you add more details.

Comment: @Ranjith yes of course i will add more detail, one minute !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you are asking to prioritize your broadcast, you can do so in androidmanifest as below:
An example:

Android documentation about the values of priority:

**android:priority**

> The priority that should be given to the parent
>   component with regard to handling intents of the type described by the
>   filter. This attribute has meaning for both activities and broadcast
>   receivers: It provides information about how able an activity is to
>   respond to an intent that matches the filter, relative to other
>   activities that could also respond to the intent. When an intent could
>   be handled by multiple activities with different priorities, Android
>   will consider only those with higher priority values as potential
>   targets for the intent. It controls the order in which broadcast
>   receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with
>   higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The
>   order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for
>   asynchronous messages.) Use this attribute only if you really need to
>   impose a specific order in which the broadcasts are received, or want
>   to force Android to prefer one activity over others.
>
> The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a
>   higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater
>   than -1000 and less than 1000.

Comment: thank you for your response , but this priority among my app broadcast receivers , and ignore other broadcast in other application

Comment: Refer to this questions accepted answer which says its not possible to do so as PHONE_STATE is is a Normal broadcast.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817178/priority-in-a-broadcast-receiver-to-receive-calls

**Normal broadcasts** (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely asynchronous. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined order, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.