# Broadcast receiver not working background on some devices

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I am trying to get WiFi connection changing event using Broadcast Receiver class. I have tested this on Samsung S7 edge and HTC 626Q and it works well (even when the app is closed), but this is not working on Huawei GR5 2017 if the app is closed. It works only when the app is running on screen. Both S7 and GR5 devices have Android 7 (Nougat) OS.

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,intent.getAction(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="chanakamadurangakarunarathne.testbroadcastevents">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I know I can use Services, but It would be nice if I can use Broadcast Receiver for all devices.
I found a lot of questions about "Broadcast Receiver not working background" but I couldn't find an answer for my question.
Why this happens and is there a way to overcome this (Using Broadcast Receiver only)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add your app to the list of "protected" apps, or the list of apps that are allowed to run in the background. On many low-end devices, and devices from Xiaomi, Huawei, etc. Android will not start (or restart) apps automatically unless they have been explicitly added to this list. Look in Settings under Battery, Power Management or Security.

See the following for more info:

- [BroadcastReceiver works for a while, then stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377792/broadcastreceiver-works-for-a-while-then-stops)
- ["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for some Huawei devices, but Huawei GR5 2017 does not have this "protected apps" feature.

Comment: I finally found a way to solve this for Huawei GR5 2017 (Nougat) model.
Settings -> Apps -> Settings icon -> Special access -> Ignore optimisations -> All apps -> (Select the app) -> Allow

Comment: Ouch! :-( That's not intuitive!

Comment: Anyone know how to resolve the same for Oppo F5. I have allowed my app under startup manager but still can't receive broadcast receiver when the app is closed.